# How to see errors when running voila on remote web server (Heroku)

Tags: docker, heroku, jupyter-notebook, voila

I deployed my voila app on Heroku with a docker file, but the web page returned to me showed that there was an error when executing a certain cell. The app worked fine on my laptop, and it takes more than 10 minutes to get my app deployed.
I could access the remote terminal, but I can't find a way to see the error messages.
Is there a simple way to see the error messages with bash or could I open a web page on the local server to display the error messages with voila --debug?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just changing CMD voila to CMD voila --debug in my dockerfile, and the error would show up in the returned web page.